# Adding extra button in AMSlideMenu navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using AMSlideMenu. [Here](http://screencast.com/t/GY9dVx2B) is my requirement. How should I add the custom button?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom `UINavigationBar` and add your `UIBarButtonItem` there, or just add on each view controller's `navigationItem`